# String.Remove substring based on index position and mixing with a for loop

Tags: c#, indexof

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "String test <123> blablabla1 </123> <123> blablabla2 </123> <123> blablabla3 </123>";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            int s1 = s.IndexOf("<123>");
            int s2 = s.IndexOf("</123>");
            int s3 = s2 - s1;
            s = s.Remove(s1, s3);
        }
        textBox.Text = s;
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
 }
```

I have the following code.
The string s contains several "blablabla#" values that I want removed.
I managed to get the first removed using simple string.remove math.
How could i make it loop for each occurrence of the starting string "<123>"?

Comment: Are you just wanting to remove all the stuff in `<123>` tags? If so you might be better off with a while loop rather than a for loop. At that point you just repeat what worked the first time until you don't find any more occurrences.

Comment: That is pretty much what I want to do, however I have never done a for or while loop.
So although my understanding matches, my syntax is limited :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace all at once with [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace):

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"<123>.*?<\/123>", "");
```

or to replace the extra spaces too:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*<123>.*?<\/123>\s*", "");
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Regex.
If i understood well:
first parameter = string
second parameter = replace the following with a wild card in between
third parameter = replace to <nothing>

Comment: @PhilZan you will probably get familiar with Regex eventually. `.` matches any character, `*` matches it 0 or more times, and `?` is to make it non-greedy so that it matches as few times as possible https://regex101.com/r/bPemY0/1

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = "String test <123> blablabla1 </123> <123> blablabla2 </123> <123> blablabla3 </123>";
    int s1;
    while ((s1 = s.IndexOf("<123>")) >= 0) 
    {
        int s2 = s.IndexOf("</123>");
        int s3 = s2 - s1;
        s = s.Remove(s1, s3);
    }
    textBox.Text = s;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend checking the second index too just in case `while ((i1 = s.IndexOf("<123>")) >= 0 && (i2 = s.IndexOf("</123>")) > i1) s = s.Remove(i1, i2 - i1 + 6);`